# Prove by Contrapositive/Contradiction/Direct

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was giving a question to prove to be true and can not determine how to go about solving this question:

> Prove that if $x$ is an integer, then $x^2 + 5x - 1$ is odd.

I have no idea how to go about this. You can't go by contrapositive because that would be saying that if $x$ is not an integer and that doesn't make sense. Is it maybe to prove by contradiction that it is even?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rewrite as 
$$x^2 + 5x - 1 = x(x + 5) - 1.$$
Now, can $x$ and $x + 5$ be **both** odd?

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

It's an easy one, you have to consider the parity.

The parity of $x^2$ is the same as the parity of $x$, and the same as the parity of $5x$, so $x^2+5x$ is even and $x^2+5x-1$ is odd.